# Serialize C# objects to specific format

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, format, xml-namespaces

I serialize a Vehicle object with the following code to serialize the object:

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Vehicle));
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(RESULTS_FILE_PATH_))
        using (XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            try
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, vehicles[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown: " + exception);
            }
        }
```

The results are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Model xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <modelYear xmlns="urn:configcompare4g.kp.chrome.com">2014</modelYear> 

            <subdivisionName xmlns="urn:configcompare4g.kp.chrome.com">Buick</subdivisionName><modelId 

    </Model>
```

I need the format to be like this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ModelArrayElement xmlns="urn:configcompare4g.kp.chrome.com">
     <model>
        <modelYear>2014</modelYear>
        <subdivisionName>Buick</subdivisionName>
     </model>
    </ModelArrayElement>
  </S:Body>
 </S:Envelope>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can produce the proper format?

Comment: This is still basically XML, try experimenting with XElement and how you output the names of them. I will go get the code from my other computer and post an answer shortly - I did exactly this last year.

Answer (score 4):

For such a serialization need to use SoapFormatter.
Detailed information can be found in the description on MSDN 
([SoapFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter.aspx)).

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. The results produced the following format: <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.....etc. Which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

If your XML output is non-standard and it will be difficult to use any default formatter, I would think about using some templating engine, like [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/), so it would be something like:

```
string template = 
@"<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">"+
  "<S:Body>"+
  "   <ModelArrayElement xmlns="urn:configcompare4g.kp.chrome.com">"+
  "      <model>"+
  "         <modelYear>@Model.modelYear</modelYear>"+
  "         <subdivisionName>@Model.subdivisionName</subdivisionName>"+
  "      </model>"+
  "    </ModelArrayElement>"+
  "</S:Body>"+
  "</S:Envelope>";

var model = vehicles[0];
string result = Razor.Parse(template, model);
```

This gives a complete control of output and allows to make more complex logic based on loops, conditionals etc.

Comment: @DStanley, you will write a few templates then. OP does not mention how many models exists and how complicated they are. I am using such solution in my software because Razor allows you to use more complicated logic like loops and conditions. In my opinion this suggestion does not deserve down vote.